# How to provide test ESModule implementation in mocha test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, esmodules

I have a mocha test which tests my code. My code uses another "core" npm package (which uses CommonJS modules). One of "core" the files ("synchronizer.js" file) `require`s "prefs" modules which is assumed to be provided at some point:

```
const {Prefs} = require("prefs");
```

In the mocha test i'd like to implement this "prefs" module, so i've created "prefs.mjs" file (with exports that "synchronizer.js" expects). However during the test i have the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'prefs'
Require stack:
- /Users/developer/Documents/dev/src/project/node_modules/core/lib/synchronizer.js
- /Users/developer/Documents/dev/src/project/node_modules/core/lib/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:872:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/developer/Documents/dev/src/project/node_modules/core/lib/synchronizer.js:26:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/developer/Documents/dev/src/project/node_modules/core/lib/index.js:33:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

My project structure:

```
\sdk
\test
     \unit
          \ prefs
                 \prefs.mjs
          \test.js
```

I run the tests (`package.json`):

```
   "dependencies": {
     ...
     "core": "^0.10.1",
     ...
   },
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "unittest": "mocha --recursive ./test/unit/*.js",
     ...
   }
}
```

`test.js` looks as follows:

```
describe("Section1", function() {
  beforeEach(async function() {
    await configureTestEnv();

    // TODO: set "prefs" module
    // TODO: set "io" module
    // TODO: set "info" module
  });

  describe("subscriptions", function() {
    it("throws if no condition is achieved", async function() {
   ...
```

I can run the tests (which does not include "core") successfully, so the testing works in general.
I suspect i have to use smth like webpack or babel, but i'd like to keep it clean and not using any deps or intermediate build steps if possible.

Should i pass modules directories paths to mocha to let node.js somehow find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using webpack and generating a module with `aliase`d modules including `prefs`.